# how to control printer list when print a file (from any app) and do some other operation with the file

Tags: delphi, printers

i want to create "printer device" in delphi,
my users have some ERP application (all kind),
i want to index the files report to my DMS application.

so, i think to create some "printer device" and the user will point to "print" the file in the
printing button. in the list the user will see also my "printer" and he will point to "my printer" in the printer list,

as result "my printer" which is some dll will get the file name and then
i will seek for that file and open an Indexing form at my DMS application.
is it possible to do that?

i dont know from where to start, so i did't try ant thing.
no problem of buying components if exsists.

Comment: For that to happen, you would have to write a printer driver, which requires an executable format that Delphi does not produce.

Comment: Also, questions asking us to recommend or find components are off-topic here, which means it should not be in your question. (Components are *software libraries* - see the [help/on-topic].)

Answer (score -1):

veryPDF SDK printer do the job.
you install the printer
config the config.ini - set what exe to run and the pdf file
that it